# How to reset the form after submit or after clicking on cancel button using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik

```
const TextForm: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => { 

const formError = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().required("Required"),
  });
      const formValidation = (fieldName) => {
        return {
          invalid: !!form.errors[fieldName] && form.touched[fieldName],
          invalidText: form.errors[fieldName],
          onBlur: form.handleBlur,
        };
      };  
 const form = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          name,
          id,
        },
        formValidation
        formError,
        validateOnChange: true,
        validateOnMount: true,
        initialTouched: {},
      });
  
    return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <form>
     <TextInput
                        id="text-input-2"
                        {...validation("name")}
                        type="text"
                        name = "name"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setName(event.target.value);
                          form.handleChange(event);
                        }}
                      />
    <TextInput
                        id="text-input-2"
                        {...validation("id")}
                        type="text"
                        name = "id"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          setId(event.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
    <Button>Clear</Button>
    <Button>Submit</Button>
    </form>
    </React.Fragment>
    ) 
    }
```

Validations in my form are working fine. But if user does not enter any field, it comes with required warning. I am trying to clear/reset the form on Clear button click ,but could not find any possible solution working. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: For the clear button you could try specifying the button type `type="reset"`. If no type attribute is specified for a button then `type="submit"` is the default type.

Comment: I have tries type = "rest but it wont reset the form. Resetting the form means I want the fresh form and clear all its states. I am not sure hwo to use onReset or resetForm using formik

Comment: Your snippet doesn't have *any* button types specified. Please update snippet to be the *actual* code with issue, otherwise we're just guessing as to what the issue may be.

Comment: As @DrewReese mentioned try  <Button type="reset">Reset </Button> it will work.
for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583815/formik-how-to-reset-form-after-confirmation#:~:text=what%20resetForm%20can%20do%3F,what's%20passed%20as%20an%20argument.

Comment: Checkout this answer, might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180883/5032733

Answer (score 5):

A quick search of the Formik docs.

The Formik `onSubmit` and `onReset` are passed [`formikBag`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#formik-render-methods-and-props) as their second argument, of which contains the `resetForm` action. The `resetForm` callback can be destructured from this `formikBag` object and used within *your* callback.

[onSubmit](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany)
[onReset](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onreset-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void)

```
const form = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    name,
    id,
  },
  formValidation
  formError,
  validateOnChange: true,
  validateOnMount: true,
  initialTouched: {},
  onSubmit: (values, { resetForm }) => {
    // submission logic
    resetForm();
  },
  onReset: (values, { resetForm }) => resetForm(),
});
```

You also just need to ensure your form buttons have the correct button types so the form takes the correct action when clicked.

Comment: Thanks.That's really helpful , but is there any way to reset the form without setting the button type as reset?  I have my form in the Modal. And I dont have access to the buttons which comes with the modal.

Comment: @Singh Hmm, this is really just how `form` and `button` elements work in semantic HTML (*for obvious accessibility reasons*). In your snippet the buttons are part of the form, you *should* have a bit of control over them (assuming the `Button` is designed/implemented in a reasonable manner).

Comment: @Singh If you are able to update your question with how the form is used within your modal code we may be able to come up with a solution.